# What is the meaning of the name of the Z3 SMT solver?

Tags: z3

The Z3 SMT solver from Microsoft Research is widely viewed as a leader in its field.

Is there any meaning behind the name "Z3" or is it purely a random project name?  I have looked through several papers and slides that introduce the project, but none of them seem to explain the name.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is neither programming-related no otherwise technical, and thus outside the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: The main reason I asked the question here is the Z3 project lists StackOverflow as its main community site, so I wasn't sure where else to ask.

Comment: I'd like to know as well. I always gathered it was a nod to Konrad Zuse's Z3 computer for its innovativeness and the BMW Z3 for its speed, but this is pure speculation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Z3" in the name [Z3 SMT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_Theorem_Prover) (SMT = [Satisfiability modulo theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories)) is based on a previous Microsoft solver called Zapatho. Basically, higher versions had more functions but a shorter name. It went from

1. Zapatho
2. Zap2
3. Z3

Explained by Nikolaj Bjørner in [Z3 and SMT in Industrial R&D](http://t-news.cn/Floc2018/FLoC2018-pages/proceedings_paper_275.pdf):

> Microsoft Research was also an incubator to the SLAM symbolic model checker, which had instigated the previous generations of SMT solvers at Microsoft: Zapatho solved integer difference logic and uninterpreted functions, Zap2 (dropping “atho”) extended the scope to full linear arithmetic, uninterpreted functions, arrays and quantifiers,and Leonardo de Moura and I created a v. 3 from scratch, Z3, dropping “ap”.

(Originally: N Bjørner, "Z3 and SMT in Industrial R&D" in: K Havelund, J Peleska, B Roscoe, E de Vink: "Formal Methods: 22nd International Symposium, FM 2018, Held as Part of the Federated Logic Conference, FloC 2018, Oxford, UK, July 15-17, 2018, Proceedings", Springer, p. 676.)

Comment: I didn't find out anything about that earlier Zapatho and this article is the only source I found mentioning it. Perhaps, Zapatho was never published and only used internally in R&D.